# Visual Studio Pro 2013 Always Wants to Setup

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, repair

Every time I try to open my Visual Studio Pro 2013 application, it brings me to the menu that asks to "Modify", "Repair", or "Uninstall." Three times today, and every time I try to open the program, it brings up this window and I tell it to repair. Every single time today I have repaired it, it takes more than an hour to complete, and then at the end it brings up a window that says setup is complete. The only option then is to close the window. However, I then go and try to open the program, and I get the same darn menu asking to modify, repair, or uninstall.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the program, and hitting repair multiple times, but the program hardly ever actually runs. I think in the month I've had it, it has only successfully opened and run twice.

How do I make it run every time I open?

Comment: Which version of windows do you have? Which service packs? Try looking in the Windows event viewer for errors related to visual studio and post the full message and stack traces in your question

Comment: I have windows 8, and I have the full download of VS Pro 2013 with update 4.

Comment: Can you check the Windows Event Viewer for errors or warnings when starting Visual Studio? This should give us a lead.